# Testing jquery views with jasmine and node on command line, no window

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

While testing my Backbone app using `jasmine` on the command line, I ran into the small issue that when one of my `collections` or `views` makes use of `jquery`, I have no window to work with and so jquery throws the no window error.

Naturally I can't use something like `jsdom` since this would override my actual window when the `view` is being implemented in the browser. The issue isn't using jquery in the actual spec file since I can use `jsdom` here.

So, is there a way to set jquery to the correct version from within my views or collections? I tried the following but jquery still fails to see the window:

```
if (global.window) {
    $ = require('jquery');
} else {
    var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
    global.window = jsdom().parentWindow;
    $ = require("jquery")(window);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend running your test with the help of KarmaJS - http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html

A headless browser, so you're running everthing like in a browser environment including window.

Comment: so there is no way without having to bring in another testing framework like Karma? I was hoping to do it all with just jasmine

Comment: Actually it's not a framework, it's a test running environment. I assume you're doing it now with nodejs? I don't have experience how reliable window object mocks are. We just used Karma and it worked.

Comment: fantastic, will give it a go